# How to set TextMate Soft Tabs to 1?

Tags: textmate

I want my tabs to be 1 space only, however, TextMate does not let me do it. Is there a way of doing it?

thanks

Comment: Why would you do that? Hitting the tab character would then just be identical to hitting the space character.

Comment: It doesn't seem like that :/ my tab is still 2 spaces and not 1 as I thought it would be. Even with the "soft tab" activated.

Answer (score 4):

Click the tab size popup in the status bar, enable soft tabs, select "other..." and set it to 1.
[image: Soft Tabs]
Source- the textmate website:

4.11 Using Spaces Instead of Tabs

TextMate can use spaces instead of tab characters. This is done by clicking the “Tab Size” pop-up in the status bar and enabling Soft Tabs.

This setting will only affect the current language and all languages with a common root that do not have the option set yet. The same applies to the state of spell checking, soft wrap and the actual tab size.

When soft tabs are enabled, TextMate will for the most part act exactly as if you were using hard tabs but the document does indeed contain spaces.

Comment: @swiecki how to make it to 1 space?

Comment: If you want 1 space tabs, why not use space then?

Answer (score 2):

set a `.tm_properties` file in either `~/` or your `project root` to with the following content:

```
softTabs = true
tabSize = 1
```

Your preference is, like comments imply, rather strange, but serviceable nonetheless.

Comment: also, there's a `gear` icon in the file browser, and clicking on 'Preferences' will open the .tm_properties file for you.